# show that $x+y+z\ge 2$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x,y,z\ge 0$. If
>   $$x^{2016}y^{2016}+y^{2016}z^{2016}+x^{2016}z^{2016}=1$$ then show
>   that $$x+y+z\ge 2$$

I have tried
$$(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+xz)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left[ (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right] \ge 0$$
so we have
$$(x+y+z)^2\ge 3(xy+yz+xz)$$
but I am stuck here. How could I continue this proof?

Comment: I suggest you examine which sets $(x, y, z)$ in the neighbourhood of $(1, 1, 0)$ satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 5):

For $z=0$ and $x=y=1$ we get a value $2$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^{4032}\geq\sum_{cyc}x^{2016}y^{2016},$$
for which we'll prove the following.

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be non-negative numbers and nutural $n\geq2$. Prove that:
$$\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^{2n}\geq x^ny^n+x^nz^n+y^nz^n.$$
1. $n=2$.

We need to prove that 
$$(x+y+z)^4\geq16(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2).$$
Indeed, by AM-GM
$$(x+y+z)^4=\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)\right)^2\geq8\sum_{cyc}x^2\sum_{cyc}xy=$$
$$=8\sum_{cyc}(x^3y+x^3z+x^2yz)\geq8\sum_{cyc}(x^3y+x^3z)\geq8\sum_{cyc}(2x^2y^2)=16(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2).$$
2. Now, $$\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^{2k+2}=\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^{2k-2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\sum_{cyc}x^{k-1}y^{k-1}=\sum_{cyc}(x^{k+1}y^{k+1}+x^{k+1}y^{k-1}z^2+x^{k+1}z^{k-1}y^2)\geq$$
$$\geq x^{k+1}y^{k+1}+x^{k+1}z^{k+1}+y^{k+1}z^{k+1}.$$
Thus, by induction for ending of the proof it remains to prove that
$$(x+y+z)^6\geq64(x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3).$$
We can make it by the similar way:
$$(x+y+z)^6=(x+y+z)^4\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)\geq16\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)=$$
$$=16\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2+x^2y^2z^2+2x^3y^3+2z^3y^2z+2x^3z^2y)\geq$$
$$\geq16\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2+2x^3y^3)\geq16\sum_{cyc}(2x^3y^3+2x^3y^3)=64\sum_{cyc}x^3y^3$$
and we are done!

Comment: A little improvement of your induction step: Notice that $\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2 \ge xy$ since $(x-y)^2 + z^2 + 2yz + 2zx \ge 0$. Similarly $\left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2 \ge yz$ and $\left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right) \ge zx$. Thus $\left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^{2k+2} \ge \left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2(x^ky^k + y^kz^k + x^kz^k) = \left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2x^ky^k + \left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2y^kz^k + \left( \frac{x+y+z}{2} \right)^2z^kx^k \ge xy(x^ky^k) + yz(y^kz^k) + zx(z^kx^k)$.

Comment: @Siddharth Joshi You proved that $3\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2}\right)^2\geq xy+xz+yz$ and it does not help. Even $(x+y+z)^2\geq3(xy+xz+yz)$ does not help!

Comment: No I'm only proving the hypothesis for $k + 1$ provided that it holds for $k$. Can you point out what's wrong with my arguement?

Comment: @Siddharth Now I see it! It's nice!